# Error when applies an affine transformation to an image in opencv2

Tags: java, opencv

I deskew image with warpAffine function in java, but when i run it notices:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3) in warpAffine
```

This is my function:

```
private  Mat deskew(Mat image,boolean negated){
        if(!negated) {
            for (int row = 0; row < image.rows(); row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < image.cols(); col++) {
                    double value = 255 - image.get(row, col)[0];
                    image.put(row, col, value);
                }
            }
        }
        Moments m = Imgproc.moments(image);
        if(Math.abs(m.get_m02()) < 1e-2) {
            return image;
        }
        double skew = m.get_m11() / m.get_m02();
        int rows = 2,cols = 3;
        Size size = new Size(rows,cols);

        Mat M = new Mat(size,CvType.CV_32F);
        M.put(0, 0, 1.0);
        M.put(0, 1, skew);
        M.put(0, 2, -0.5*image.rows()*skew);
        M.put(1, 0, 0.0);
        M.put(1, 1, 1.0);
        M.put(1, 2, 0.0);
        Mat imagedst = new Mat();
        Imgproc.warpAffine(image, imagedst, M, image.size(),Imgproc.WARP_INVERSE_MAP|Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
        return imagedst;
    }
```

I think when i initialize Mat M with CvType.CV_32F type is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `M` is wrong.

`Size` expects `(width, height)`, not `(rows, cols)`. So you need to create `size` as:

```
Size size = new Size(cols,rows);
Mat M = new Mat(size, CvType.CV_32F);
```

Or you can create `M` as:

```
Mat M = new Mat(rows, cols, CvType.CV_32F);
```